# SQLite only one column get updated Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a Sqlite database that works fine, I can insert rows with no problem, but when I try to do an update only one column get updated. I get a return value of 1, but only the column SCANNED get updated, that is the only column that already had a value of 0 and was change to 1.

```
public int UpdateScanInvoice(String Invoice, int scanned, String empname, 
              int empnum) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",Locale.US);
        String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss",Locale.US);
        String formattedTime = tf.format(c.getTime());
        String strFilter = MySQLiteHelper.TICKETNR + "='" + Invoice +"'";
        ContentValues scanvalues = new ContentValues();
            scanvalues.put(MySQLiteHelper.LOADEMPNAME, empname);
        scanvalues.put(MySQLiteHelper.SCANNED, scanned);
        scanvalues.put(MySQLiteHelper.LOADEMPNUM, empnum);
        scanvalues.put(MySQLiteHelper.LOADDATE,formattedDate);
        scanvalues.put(MySQLiteHelper.LOADTIME, formattedTime);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        int rowUpdated = db.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_INVOICE, scanvalues,strFilter, null);
        return rowUpdated;
    }
```

Maybe my original insert is wrong?
This is the original insert.

```
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.SCANNED, 0);
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.LOADDATE, "");
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.LOADTIME, "");
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.LOADEMPNAME, "");
values.put(MySQLiteHelper.LOADEMPNUM, "");
```

I the file has 19 columns and only the last 4 will not update or take any value when I do an insert.
I deleted the data recreated the database, same result.

Thanks,
KimHJ

Comment: Can you please provide your log details.

Comment: Post the result of `Log.v("Results","="+Invoice+" "+scanned+" "+empname+" "+empnum)`.

Comment: Where will I find the Log?

Comment: Here is the log: Results =X1234 1 Rick 42

Answer (score 1):

Why are you again updating all the values You want to change the SCANNED value for that just update that value only like this..

```
    scanvalues.put(MySQLiteHelper.SCANNED, scanned);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowUpdated = db.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_INVOICE, scanvalues,strFilter, null);
```

for updating only SCANNED this is enough but you are updating all the values..this will replace your all old data

Comment: The problem is I want to update all values, but only scanned get updated.